# Как я могу получить количество элементов в коллекции в другом методе?

Tags: java, коллекции

```java
public class StringPool {
    
private List<String> anek = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public String stringPool() {
        anek.add("...");
        anek.add("...");
        anek.add("...");

        return aned.get(randomIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Для этого у коллекций есть метод **.size()**

Comment: Язык программирования то хоть какой? Добавьте тег.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, метод `stringPool` должен возвращать некоторое значение из списка `anek` случайным образом, наиболее простая реализация без побочных эффектов типа изменения коллекции при вызове метода может выглядеть так:

```java
public String getRandomAnek() {
    return anek.get(new Random().nextInt(anek.size()));
}
```

Заполнение/добавление элементов коллекции следует выполнять отдельно (в конструкторе / блоке инициализации / отдельном методе).

```java
private List<String> anek = new ArrayList<String>();
{
    anek.add("...1");
    anek.add("...2");
    anek.add("...3");
}

public void addStringToPool(String str) {
    anek.add(str);
}

public void setPool(Collection<String> data) {
    anek.clear();
    anek.addAll(data);
}
```